# How do I create a manual lock on an atomic property's ivar in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I want to expose an atomic property in my obj-c class, but internally I'd prefer to access it's instance var directly rather using `self.myproperty` for every reference.  How do you manually create a lock to block the external read?

So I want...

```
@property (atomic, strong) NSString *someString;

- myInternalMethodOfClassA
{
    ...
    @synchronized(someString) {
        someString = @"New string";
    }
    ...
}
```

...to block...

```
- myInstanceMethodInClientClassB 
{
    ClassA *myobj = [ClassA alloc] init];

    ...
    NSString *str = myobj.someString;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [some chat on the Apple Objc-lang list](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Jan/msg00034.html), it's considered a bug to have an atomic property for which you manually create one accessor and synthesize the other.  The alternatives are:

1. Create both accessors yourself and use a bespoke locking object plus `@synchronized(anObject)`, which you can then use elsewhere in your class's code.
2. `@synthesize` them and always access them via their accessors (ie `self.myAtomicProp` internally).  This is slower but most likely not a problem in nearly all cases.